# Why is ansible kubernetes not finding kube config while kubectl does

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, k3s

I have a server that is running k3s and I'm trying to install a few things on it using ansible.
The ansible task is this one here:

```
- name: Create lb
  kubernetes.core.k8s:
    state: present
    src: /opt/metallb/metallb-native.yaml
```

But it fails with `Could not create API client: Invalid kube-config file. No configuration found.`.
I made sure that there is a config file in `~/.kube/config` and I also don't have any problems when running:

```
- name: test kubectl 
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: kubectl get nodes
```

The logs I get with `-vvv` are:

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_payload_tu6hy1j6/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_payload.zip/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core/plugins/module_utils/k8s/client.py", line 153, in _create_configuration
    kubernetes.config.load_incluster_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/kubernetes/config/incluster_config.py", line 121, in load_incluster_config
    try_refresh_token=try_refresh_token).load_and_set(client_configuration)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/kubernetes/config/incluster_config.py", line 54, in load_and_set
    self._load_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/kubernetes/config/incluster_config.py", line 62, in _load_config
    raise ConfigException("Service host/port is not set.")
kubernetes.config.config_exception.ConfigException: Service host/port is not set.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_payload_tu6hy1j6/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_payload.zip/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core/plugins/module_utils/k8s/client.py", line 351, in get_api_client
    configuration = _create_configuration(auth_spec)
  File "/tmp/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_payload_tu6hy1j6/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_payload.zip/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core/plugins/module_utils/k8s/client.py", line 158, in _create_configuration
    raise err
  File "/tmp/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_payload_tu6hy1j6/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_payload.zip/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core/plugins/module_utils/k8s/client.py", line 156, in _create_configuration
    _load_config(auth)
  File "/tmp/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_payload_tu6hy1j6/ansible_kubernetes.core.k8s_payload.zip/ansible_collections/kubernetes/core/plugins/module_utils/k8s/client.py", line 126, in _load_config
    kubernetes.config.load_kube_config(config_file=None, **optional_arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 815, in load_kube_config
    loader = _get_kube_config_loader(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 772, in _get_kube_config_loader
    raise ConfigException(
kubernetes.config.config_exception.ConfigException: Invalid kube-config file. No configuration found.
```

Why is the kubernetes module not able to find the configs, while running `kubectl` in a shell works?
And how can I get the kubernetes module working?

Comment: The fact that the error is `Service host/port is not set.` and subsequently becomes `No configuration found.` make me wonder if really it does not read your configuration file or if it just fails with the first exception and, then, gives you a misleading one.

Comment: In the setup you have whether "kube config" directory exists in your home directory.  more details are in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_module.html#parameter-kubeconfig.   Also kubectl client by default refers to "~/.kube/config" directory so if you need to set different context you can do by specifying config set-context

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε yes I also thought about that, but in the config `clusters.cluster.server` is set to `https://127.0.0.1:6443` so host and port are set. `kubectl` also doesn't complain, so there the config seems to be working

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal yes I also read through this, the config is in the default place `~/.kube/config`, but I also tried setting it explicitly with an absolute path, and it still could not find it. 
It's also run from the same user as the `kubectl` task, so `~` is the same anyways

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

In the `ansible-vault` I was using, `become_password` was set, so all tasks were executing under root. This changed the `~` directory, which no longer contained the kube config.

Why it still did not work with absolute paths I'm not sure, but setting

```
- name: name of task
  kubernetes.core.k8s:
    kubeconfig: "~{{ansible_user}}/.kube/config"
    ...
```

Will take the users config whether `become` set or not